# No payment method are dispaying during creating order from backend

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, backend, create

I tried to create an order from the backend, but in the payment method, I can't see any information of the existing payment methods like the attached picture.

[image: payment method not showing]

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @ youssef , @evilscary : Did you solved this issue.

Comment: @JeevaRathinam I finally worked out that the issue was caused by a clash between two modules I had installed. I uninstalled them and it fixed the bug. I'm afraid I can't remember which modules it was though, although they were both to do with payments I think.

Answer (score 3):

what payment methods have you activated in `System > Config > SALES > Payment Methods`?

Anyway consider that the majority of the "on-line" payment methods are not available in the backend even if they have been activated.

This is due to the fact that Magento checks for the `$_canUseInternal` protected property of the Payment Method class (extending `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`) that is usually set to `false` for on-line payment methods like PayPal.

The rationale is that on-line payment methods require the user inserting private data which are not (or should not be) available to merchants (like Customers' PayPal account or Credit Card Number).

Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Thank you Alessandro. I know that the on-line payment methods are not available in the backend.
I want just to show the payment like "Cash on delivery", but I think I have displaying problem, because by default it shows "No Payment Information Required". But in our case we have nothing displayed. What can I do thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go to the the following; System / Sales / Payment Method

Activate which ever one you need to use or any which needs or have been configured to a payment gateway. You can activate them via core code, but would mess things up for the future. Another way is could create modals and create an observer.

Hope that helps.